# Cannot record audio without QMainWindow

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio-recording, qtmultimedia

I have trouble using `QAudioRecorder` without using `QMainWindow`. It would create a file with 0 bytes, which is not playable by most common media players after running this script here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QAudioRecorder q;
    q.setAudioInput(q.audioInputs()[0]);
    q.setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("simon.amr"));
    q.record();
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

Whereas this works:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

QAudioRecorder q;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    std::cout << "DEFAULT: " << q.defaultAudioInput().toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "List: " << q.audioInputs().join(',').toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "STATUS 0: " << q.status() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Location: " << QUrl::fromLocalFile("simon.amr").path().toStdString() << std::endl;
    q.setAudioInput(q.audioInputs()[0]);
    q.setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("simon.amr"));
    q.record();

    std::cout << "STATUS 1: " << q.status() << std::endl;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    std::cout << "STATUS 2: " << q.status() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow recorder;
    recorder.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

How can I use `QAudioRecorder` without `QMainWindow`? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should use `QCoreApplication` or `QApplication` because `QAudioRecorder` requires an event loop.

Comment: :o That might be it. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QAudioRecorder's internal states are managed through signals and slots.  This requires a running event loop;

[QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#details) should be used for console applications.

[QApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#details) should be used for GUI applications.

In your above example, the MainWindow isn't even necessary, it's the app.exec() where the magic is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QAudioRecorder q; 
    q.setAudioInput(q.audioInputs()[0]);    
    q.setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("simon.amr"));    
    q.record();

    return app.exec();
}
```

You need a qt event loop. Sleep does not provide the event and signal processing that QCoreApplication provides.

Please read it up or you won't come far in Qt, since this is a Qt core mechanic.

Good luck with your project!